I3 - Wrong keyboard layout chosen after login
I'm using i3 Window Manager on Ubuntu 24.04.1.
During the normal Ubuntu login, my keyboard layout is (correctly) set to US.
When I login to the Gnome shell, my keyboard layout stays as US.
BUT, when I switch to i3, the keyboard moves to gb. I need to "setxkbmap us" in the terminal for it to switch back.
I've checked in all of the obvious places where it might be set but there's no "GB" settings from what I can find.
Where else can I look?
